# How do I reclassify a data frame so that the text is indexed

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=JLSData)

DataFrame = df.transpose()
DataFrame.head()

Employees = DataFrame['Employees']
```

That is I want to be able to index the data frame by date and by the column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a copy/pastable example and desired output, this is what I can give you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=JLSData)

df = df.transpose()
df.columns = df.iloc[0, :]
df = df.iloc[1:, :]
```

Comment: Hey Cameron, Thank you so much for the answer super helpful, how did you learn this?

Comment: I'm self taught, but have been using pandas for quite a long time now. Using the indexing method of `iloc` we can select rows/columns based on their integer position. Since your column names were stuck in your first row, all I did was select that first row and set it as the column names. Then I had changed your dataset so it didnt include the original first row. See the pandas documentation on indexing here:
 [pandas indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html). A lot of it is just practice and understanding how the DataFrames work

Answer (score 0):

```
df_new = df[1:]
df_new.columns = df.iloc[0]
```

To set date column as index

```
df_new.rename(index={0:'Date'}, inplace=True)
df_new = df_new.set_index('Date')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to rename the first column that contains dates (where column name says "unnamed:0" to DATE ? If so, then do this.

```
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "whatever" })
```

where `whatever` is the name you want to give.

If you can provide a copy of the data in text format, and provide more clarity, we can try and provide a better answer.

Comment: Hey Joe I tried this but it didn't work, any recommendations?